# How to add a third author while using the gSCS2e document class?

Tags: titles

I want to write an article using `gSCS2e.tex` template available [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=gscs20&page=instructions#mp_style) with three authors with two addresses.

The template is given for two different authors, how to add one more author?

```
\documentclass{gSCS2e}

\begin{document}

\title{{\itshape Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation} \break \LaTeX\ style guide for authors (Style 2 + NLM reference style)}

\author{A.N. Author$^{\rm a}$$^{\ast}$\thanks{$^\ast$Corresponding author. Email: latex.helpdesk@tandf.co.uk
\vspace{6pt}} and I.T. Consultant$^{\rm b}$\\\vspace{6pt}  $^{a}${\em{Taylor \& Francis, 4 Park Square, Milton Park, Abingdon, UK}};
$^{b}${\em{Institut f\"{u}r Informatik, Albert-Ludwigs-Universit\"{a}t, Freiburg,
Germany}}\\\received{v3.3 released October 2013} }

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this particular document class sets up the `\author` command is a bit idiosyncratic, to put it politely. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to (re)format the template code a bit and figure out where to place the names of further authors. In the example below, I add one extra author, named "R. A. Ndom", and I provide some dummy location information for Ms. Ndom. You'll observe that I recommend using `\textsuperscript{a}` instead of `^{\rm a}`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{gSCS2e} % for Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation
\title{{\itshape Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation} \break 
\LaTeX\ style guide for authors (Style 2 + NLM reference style)}
\author{A. N. Author\textsuperscript{a}%
$^{\ast}$\thanks{$^\ast$Corresponding author. Email: latex.helpdesk@tandf.co.uk}, 
I. T. Consultant\textsuperscript{b},
and R. A. Ndom\textsuperscript{c}\\
\vspace{6pt}
\textsuperscript{a}{\em Taylor \& Francis, 4 Park Square, Milton Park, Abingdon, UK};
\textsuperscript{b}{\em Institut f\"{u}r Informatik, Albert-Ludwigs-Universit\"{a}t, Freiburg,
Germany};
\textsuperscript{c}{\em Nowhere in particular}}
\received{v3.3 released October 2013} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```